# Selenium: How do I assert that a certain element is present in a certain cell of a certain table?

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, html-table, selenium-rc

I have a table on my page which is supposed to contain a certain element. I can identify the table by its name (it has a unique name), and I can also identify the element easily. I would like to assert that the element is present on row `r`, column `c` of the table. What is the cleanest way of doing it using Selenium commands?

**Remarks:**

- I don't want to use more than the table name in order to locate it (I don't want all the `div\div\table\div\tbody\td\tr[r]\td[c]` in the code).
- I'm using Selenium within PHPUnit. Hence, I can use PHP logic for the task, though I don't want any complex logic for such a simple task.

**Clarification:**

If the element in the cell is just plain text, then I can retrieve that text like this:

`$this->getText("xpath=//table[@name='tableName']//tr[".$r."]//td[".$c."]");` (PHP)

But what if the cell has an element which is not just plain text? What if the element is a link (`link=anchor`) or a button (`//button[@type='button']`) or an image or something more complex?

I need to assert that an *element* specified by a locator of that element resides in a given cell.

Comment: Could you add an HTML example?

Comment: `\\tr[r]\td[c]` does not work?

Comment: @powtac: `\\tr[r]\td[c]` works, but `\\tr[r]\td[c]` just locates the cell. What I need to do is asserting that inside that cell (which I can locate easily with `\\tr[r]\td[c]`) resides a specified element (which I can locate using its id or something). See the clarification I've added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want `isElementPresent(...locator of element...)`.  For example:

```
$cell = "//table[@name='tableName']//tr[".$r."]/td[".$c."]";
$foundLink = $this->isElementPresent("xpath=".$cell."/a[.='".linktext."']");
$foundButton = $this->isElementPresent("xpath=".$cell."/button[@type='button']");
$foundImage = $this->isElementPresent("xpath=".$cell."/img[ends-with(@src='pretty-pony.gif')]");
```

`isElementPresent()` returns `true` if so, `false` if not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Selenium's getXpathCount

$this->("xpath=//table[@name='tableName']//tr[".$r."]//td[".$c."]//**TAG**");
This will return the number of matches the xpath gets. in your case, zero would mean a fail.